# Who is telling me "You have mail"

Tags: bash, ssh, email, motd

On a server running Ubuntu 14.04 I see `You have new mail` in the motd every time I log in via SSH.

**Q:** Who is telling me this?

Mail does not find anything, and I do not expect any mails on this server.

crontab for "me" and "root" contains `MAILTO=""` .

The text `You have new mail` is not present in `/etc/motd` or `/var/run/motd`.

Some commands I hope are relevant:

```
me@AtomServer:~$mail
No mail for me
me@AtomServer:~$sudo mail
No mail for root
me@AtomServer:~$sudo ls -l /var/mail
total 8
-rw------- 1 la   mail 1 Jul 15 22:12 me
-rw------- 1 root mail 1 Jul 27 19:59 root
me@AtomServer:~$

me@AtomServer:~$grep '^s.*motd' /etc/pam.d/sshd
session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]
me@AtomServer:~$$ls -la /etc/update-motd.d
total 48
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 13 13:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 127 root root 12288 Jul 27 20:06 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1220 Apr 19  2012 00-header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1358 Apr 19  2012 10-help-text
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    46 Jan 30 21:57 50-landscape-sysinfo -> /usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   149 Aug 22  2011 90-updates-available
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   129 Sep 30  2011 91-release-upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   129 Jun 16  2014 95-hwe-eol
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   142 Aug 22  2011 98-fsck-at-reboot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   144 Aug 22  2011 98-reboot-required
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1158 Apr 19  2012 99-footer
 me@AtomServer:~$

me@AtomServer:/etc/update-motd.d$grep -ri 'mail' *
me@AtomServer:/etc/update-motd.d$
```

`/etc/motd.tail` does not exist.

Comment: `motd` is managed by `pam_motd` module..what are the outputs of `grep '^s.*motd' /etc/pam.d/sshd` and `ls -a /etc/update-motd.d` ?

Comment: @heemayl I added the outputs to the original question.

Comment: Ok..check teh contents of the files in `/etc/update-motd.d` especially `99-footer` and `00-header` ..you can add these to your question or use http://paste.ubuntu.com and give the link here..

Comment: @heemayl http://paste.ubuntu.com/11950327/
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11950339/

Comment: what are the outputs of `cat /etc/motd.tail` (does it exist ?) and `grep -ri 'mail' /etc/update-motd.d` ?

Comment: @heemayl Added to original question!

Comment: no 'mail' in /usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper either.

Comment: Seems like it is given by shell itself..whats the output of `echo "$MAIL"` ?

Comment: me@AtomServer:~$echo "$MAIL"
/var/mail/me
me@AtomServer:~$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26311/discussion-between-heemayl-and-wirewrap).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is being done your shell itself. Apparently it is monitoring the file (or directory) pointed by the `MAIL` (or `MAILPATH`) environment variable.

This is documented in `man bash` :

```
MAIL   
       If  this  parameter  is  set  to  a file or directory name and
the MAILPATH variable is not set, bash informs the user of the arrival 
of mail in the specified file or Maildir-format directory
```

On a different note the contents of `motd` is actually governed by the PAM module `pam_motd` (the shell might have something to add though as per user configuration files).

By default `pam_motd` shows the static content of the `/etc/motd` file along with the dynamic outputs generated from running scripts in the `/etc/update-motd.d` directory (using `run-parts`).